# java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for com.timesten.jdbc.TimesTenDriver

Tags: java, eclipse, jdbc, timesten

I am getting an exception:

```
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for com.timesten.jdbc.TimesTenDriver while trying to connect to Timesten DB installed in my system.
```

The code is given below:

```
    Connection conn = null;

    try {
        Class.forName("com.timesten.jdbc.TimesTenDriver");
        conn = DriverManager
                .getConnection("com.timesten.jdbc.TimesTenDriver");
        System.out.println(conn);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        try {
            if(conn != null) {
                conn.close();
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

I am using **Java 5** & have attached **ttjdbc5.jar** in the build path of eclipse.

Can somebody help?

Answer (score 3):

```
DriverManager.getConnection("com.timesten.jdbc.TimesTenDriver")
```

cannot have class name as parameter, instead  should have **url** of the **DB** as parameter, something like

```
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:timedb://localhost");
```

or you can use

```
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:timedb://localhost:3601", "db-username", "db-password");
```

to get connection, where `db-username` and `db-password` are username/password to connect to DB server

Comment: All JDBC URLs must (by specification) be prefixed with `jdbc:<vendorprefix>:`

Answer (score 0):

Ensure the appropriate `.jar` file is kept in your library and in `DriverManager.getConnection()` remove the driver class name as parameter and pass the appropriate `URL` for your database. 
for example if your database is SQLServer, then

```
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://10.3.12.59:1433,<optional parameters>","userName","Password");
```